# MATLAB: alphaShape creates incorrect geometry particularly around filleted regions

Tags: matlab, cad

I have a 3D CAD file which I am importing into Matlab via stlread.

I then use alphaShape using the points generated from stlread of the geometry. However, the alphaShape is not accurate to my geometry and adds a whole bunch of triangles that do not match my geometry.

How can I fix this?

This is what it is supposed to be:

[image]

However, this is what I get instead:

[image]

Thanks,
I.

Comment: What code have you tried? Have you tried adjusting the [alpha radius](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alphashape.html#d120e19551)?

Comment: Hey, I have actually fiddled around with the alpha radius but at a radius that captures the correct geometry at the wall junction, it gets rid of the points in the rest of my geometry and then I am left with big gaping holes.

Comment: It seems that you have too large triangles in your wall, while to small ones in the floor. Is there something you can do in the STL generation to add more detail to the triangles?

Comment: I have tried remeshing via the remeshing modifier in Blender and even with an extemely fine mesh, I am still getting this weird triangulation, it is just a bit finer.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea on how I could possibly go in and edit the triangulation? Or alternatively, another function in matlab that can allow me the same thing as alphaShape? Should I edit the mesh further? I have tried everything that I can think of!